# I'm using @media query but the codes I wrote on different screens don't work

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, responsive

My first question on this site. sorry if i did anything wrong

This is my @media query code;

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width:992px) and (max-device-width:1199px){
  .container{
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

I don't know why, but it's not working on different screens.

Answer (score 0):

As i guess you want it to apply on window resize also, just change `min-device-width` and `max-device-width` to `min-width` and `max-width`, and it'll work as expected. This way it applies depending on the window width, not on the device width.

Moreover, device-width is now deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/device-width ;)

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: I've tried. However, I am still getting the error.

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Consider sharing your HTML, and its relevant CSS code, so that we can check what other things may be interfering.

Comment: You can edit your main post and add a full working fiddle with your relevant HTML and CSS codes. Here a full explanation on how to do it: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do